# Get the effective viewbox of an <svg> element?

Tags: javascript, svg, position, viewbox

An [`<svg>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) element is allowed to have a `viewBox` and a `preserveAspectRatio` attribute, which together determine the actual viewbox that is displayed on screen.

The `viewBox` attribute specifies a rectangle in SVG coordinates, which implicitly specifies an aspect ratio.  This aspect ratio may not in general be the same as that of the SVG element.  The `preserveAspectRatio` attribute specifies whether to adjust the zoom so that the entire specified viewbox fits into the SVG element or adjust the zoom so that the entire SVG element fits into the specified viewbox, as well as the alignment when performing this fitting.

From JavaScript, I would like to convert a mouse position (`offsetX`/`offsetY`) to SVG coordinates.  This necessitates finding out the transformation from screen/offset coordinates to SVG coordinates, which depends on the SVG viewbox.  Instead of doing math to calculate the actual SVG viewbox (with the same aspect ratio as the SVG element) manually from the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes, does SVG expose any interface that I can simply call to get the computed viewbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need is a [DOMPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint) and its relative position according to the SVGs [DOMMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix). That  is as fare as I can explain it.

So, here an example where the SVG is squeezed in height and you can see that the point where you click matches the viewBox size.

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('svg01');
const print = document.getElementById('print');

const toSVGPoint = (svg, x, y) => {
  let p = new DOMPoint(x, y);
  return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
};

svg.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let p = toSVGPoint(e.target, e.clientX, e.clientY);
  print.textContent = `x: ${p.x} - y: ${p.y}`;
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: thin solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p id="print">Position</p>
<svg id="svg01" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  viewBox="0 0 1000 500" preserveAspectRatio="none"
  width="400" height="150">
  <text font-size="100" x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle"
  text-anchor="middle" pointer-event="none">Click me...</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for!  Unfortunately, Safari seems to not implement `getScreenCTM()` correctly...